# User list from SAP CMC is not displaying

Tags: crystal-reports, business-intelligence, business-objects

I am trying to open User list from SAP CMC, but unfortunately a popup was displayed instead of the users, LDAP users and Enterprise users are there in the list, following is the error displayed:

> Unexpected error decoding JSF component: {0}
>
> [image]

when I am trying to schedule the report, following error is displaying:

> HTTP Status 500
>
> [image]

Please help to resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

The only clue to me as to what is wrong is this line in the error message in your screenshot:

```
The SAP security plugin failed ot get SAP user/group attribute
```

So, it appears to be an issue relating to SAP authentication.  If you not using that, check the settings in CMC -> Authentication -> SAP to make sure there's nothing there.  Other than that, I can only suggest opening a case with SAP.